# modrewrite not redirecting using htaccess

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

When i type domain.ca/keyword.html it should render using domain.ca/keyword.php but it does not. This is all i have in my htaccess file.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /   

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots.txt$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} robots\.txt [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://domain.ca/robots.txt [R=301,L]
```

Comment: And want it if .html exists use it if it doesnt search for .php

Comment: I tested your exact code on my live host and it worked just fine. Do you have any other Rewrite code in your .htaccess that actually working correctly? Maybe it has something to do with your host configuration.